# How to check for integer string

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write a program that takes in a string representing an integer as input, and outputs yes if every character is a digit 0-9.

I have gone back through my chapters reading and gone through Google, but I'm still having trouble.  I know my code is a mess but I am lost.  I may have bits and pieces correct or be wrong all together but this is what I have.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userString;
  // Add more variables as needed

      userString = scnr.next();
      boolean check1 = Character.isDigit(userString);
  
      while (check1 = True) {
         System.out.println ("Yes");
    }
      System.out.println ("No");
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Umm, Does this code compile?

Comment: 1. You are mixing up if-statement with a while loop. 2. You are mixing up comparing (==) with assigning (=) 3. You have a typo in `true`. Java is case sensitive and that keyword is all lower case. 4. You are missing parenthesis to close your methods.

Comment: Did you learn about method [parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) in class `java.lang.Integer`?

Comment: Do you want to take input just once or do you want to take input again and again? I see you're using `while` loop.

Comment: for this assignment it gave a hint that said use a loop and the Character.isDigit() function but no where can I find anything about the function is this chapter. so I do not know if I am even calling the function.

Comment: I am able to add variable as needed is there a way to convert the string that is given as input into in int??

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions for that:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// your input, can also be from a scanner
String input = "1234567890";

// regex pattern to match a string that consists only of numbers and is also not empty
String regex = "^[0-9]+$";

// to match negative numbers as well: "^[\\-]?[0-9]+$"

// create a pattern object
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

// create a matcher object
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

// check if the input matches
if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println("It's a number, yay!");
};
```

How does the regex work:

- `^` matches the beginning of the input to make sure there is nothing before the number characters
- `[0-9]+` tells it to match the range `0-9` one or more times (`+`), which also makes sure that an empty string does not match
- `$` matches the end of the string to make sure there is no non-numbers after the match

If you want to match negative numbers as well, there is an additional part of the regex: `[\\-]?` this matches one minus sign if there is on or none if there is no sign (`?`)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

It's also possible the way you tried it:

```java
// open a scanner
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// read user input from the scanner
String input = scanner.next();

// assume it is a number until we find a non-digit character below
String isNumber = true;

// loop over each character of the user input
for (char character : input) {
  // check if the character is not a digit
  if (!Character.isDigit(character)) {
    System.out.println("NOT a number: ", character);

    // set the is number variable to false
    isNumber = false;

    // break the loop, because it cannot be a number because we already found a non-digit
    break;
  };
};

System.out.println("Is it a number? ", isNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by people in comments, there are some mistakes in your code. `Character.isDigit` won't work with String. What you need to use is `Integer.parseInt(...)`. You can put it in a try catch block; Print yes if parsing is successful and print No if exception is thrown:

```java
userString = scnr.next();
try {
  int parsedValue = Integer.parseInt(userString);
  // Do something with parsedValue
  System.out.println("Yes");
} catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
  System.out.println("No");
}
```